# My website I just hosted on Google Cloud shows blank

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I just put up my website files and database on Google cloud.

When i access it via website.appspot.com, it shows a blank page. Also I cant access the static resources such as website.appspot.com/images/features.png

When I view log, I see only these:

```
2013-11-14 20:41:12.107 /favicon.ico 200 61ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.19 module=default version=1

41.203.69.6 - - [14/Nov/2013:11:41:12 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.19" "gcdc2013-myworkset.appspot.com" ms=61 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.8.7 


2013-11-14 20:41:11.549 / 404 142ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.19 module=default version=1

41.203.69.6 - - [14/Nov/2013:11:41:11 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 26 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0 AlexaToolbar/alxf-2.19" "gcdc2013-myworkset.appspot.com" ms=142 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000003 loading_request=1 app_engine_release=1.8.7 instance=00c61b117ceec79a7aa048437e41f62f131610

I 2013-11-14 20:41:11.548

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

This is the content of my app.yaml

```
application: gcdc2013-myworkset
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: index.php

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /index\.php
  script: index.php

- url: /features
  script: features/index.php

- url: /about
  script: about/index.php

- url: /oauth2callback/?
  script: signup.php  

- url: (.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)
  static_files: $1.$2
  upload: (.*).(.*)

- url: /css
  static_dir: css


- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

What exactly am I missing?

NEW APP.YAML

```
application: gcdc2013-myworkset
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /features
  script: features/index.php

- url: /about
  script: about/index.php

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /index.php
  script: index.php

- url: (.*).php
  script: $1.php

- url: /oauth2callback/?
  script: signup.php  

#- url: (.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)
#  static_files: $1.$2
#  upload: (.*).(.*)
```

Comment: Are you sure your ID is `website.appspot.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all of the entries that point to the index.php script apart from the .* one which you should move to the bottom of your app.yaml file.

What is happening is that your .* entry is matching all requests and so the entries lower down are never being processed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, was very helpful. Please check my update for the new app.yaml. The index page, /features/, /about/ that are explicitly specified in the file. Challenge is how do i target other files like: website.appspot.com/signup.php, website.appspot.com/plans.php, website.appspot.com/contact.php, website.appspot.com/import/a.php, website.appspot.com/export/export.php without having to list all files one by one?

Comment: for starters change 'script: $1.php' to 'script: \1.php'